# How to execute 2 firebase queries in a function to retrieve data react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to execute two firebase requests in a function in React Native but it's causing problems.

I first try to get the field "city" in the collection of the user currently connected to know in which city he is located.

Then I try to retrieve the delivery data from the database and display it to the user. And to sort the deliveries by city so that he can see only the deliveries around him.

My reasoning is the following:

I use useState to retrieve the city of the user then I use this information to sort the cities, all this in 2 functions called in my useEffect, I also need the data to be updated in real time (I use onSnapshot) for that. Then I pass in another view the delivery information so that the user can take care of the order.

```
export default function Notifications({ navigation }) {
  const userUID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  const dbh = firebase.firestore();

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true); // Set loading to true on component mount
  const [deliveries, setDeliveries] = useState([]); // Initial empty array of users
  const [userCity, setUserCity] = useState(""); // Initial empty array of users

  useEffect(() => {

    const userci = dbh.collection("users").                 // Fetching city field in user data
    .doc(userUID)
    .onSnapshot((doc) => {
      const usercit = (doc.data().city);
      setUserCity(usercit);
    })


    const subscriber =  dbh
    .collection("deliveries")      // Recover deliveries around him according to his city    
    .where("taken", "==", false)
    .where("city", "==", userCity)
    .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
      const deliveries = [];

      querySnapshot.forEach((documentSnapshot) => {
        deliveries.push({
          ...documentSnapshot.data(),
          key: documentSnapshot.id,
        });
      });

      setDeliveries(deliveries);
      setLoading(false);
  });
    return () => subscriber();
    }, []);
```

Here is the implementation of the fetched data :

````
  return (
      <View>
        <View>
          <TextNotifications</Text>
        </View>
        <FlatList
          data={deliveries}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => {
                navigation.navigate("DetailScreen", {
                  data: item
                })
              }}>
              <View>
                <Text>{getDate(item.when)}</Text>
                <View>
                  <Text>{item.zip_donator}</Text>
                  <Text>{item.zip_tob_deliv}</Text>
                </View>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );

```
````

Comment: "but it's causing problems and I can't find a solution to my problem." - You never state the problem (or problems?) in your question - please update your question.

Comment: It looks like your 2nd request to Firestore is dependent on the first as it is going to return the user city and you need the city in the 2nd request. So you can't use a `Promise.all()`. Even if you were able to, it was still going to cost you 2 firestore reads so I don't see any cons. If the intention is to make the code cleaner then you can just use async-await.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your effect has parts that depend on each other, you should split up the `useEffect` into sections that relate to the data that it affects as suggested in [@TarikHuber's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5519300/tarik-huber) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67216168/3068190).

However, in your current code, you also make use of `firebase.auth().currentUser` which will give the wrong value depending on when you navigate to this screen.

In React, the correct way to get the user would be to attach a listener to [`onAuthStateChanged`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onauthstatechanged) as described in the [Authentication docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user). Using this listener, you can make sure the user is properly logged in and also update it when the user signs out or switches accounts.

```js
// Attach listeners for user object
// - user is unknown until state is resolved
// - onAuthStateChanged returns it's unsubscribe function
// - useEffect is given [], so it only runs on mount and unmount, not renders
const [user, setUser] = useState(undefined); // unknown until state is resolved
useEffect(() => firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(setUser), []);
```

Combining this with your code, and correcting for other intermediate states (like updating the user's city), gives:

```js
export default function Notifications({ navigation }) {
  const dbh = firebase.firestore();

  // Attach listeners for user object
  // - user is unknown until state is resolved
  // - onAuthStateChanged returns it's unsubscribe function
  // - useEffect is given [], so it only runs on mount and unmount, not renders
  const [user, setUser] = useState(undefined); // initially, user state is unknown
  useEffect(() => firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(setUser), []);
  
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true); // Set loading to true on component mount
  const [deliveries, setDeliveries] = useState([]); // initially, there are no deliveries to show
  const [userCity, setUserCity] = useState(undefined); // initially, the user's city is unknown
  
  // if user is logged out, force them to the Login screen
  if (user === null) {
    navigation.navigate('Login');
    return null;
  }

  // Effect to manage the userCity variable
  useEffect(() => {
    if (user === undefined) {
      // still loading initial user state, do nothing.
      return;
    }
    
    if (user === null) {
      // no user signed in!
      setUserCity(undefined);
      return;
    }
    
    // Fetch city field in user's data
    const unsubscriber = dbh
      .collection("users")
      .doc(user.uid)
      .onSnapshot((doc) => {
        // TODO: Handle when user doesn't have a city
        const city = doc.get("city");
        setUserCity(city);
      });
    return unsubscriber;
  }, [user]); // rerun this effect only if user is updated

  // Effect to manage the deliveries variable
  useEffect(() => {
    if (user === undefined) {
      // still loading initial user state, do nothing.
      return;
    }
    
    if (user === null) {
      // no user signed in!
      setDeliveries([]); // no deliveries to show at this time
      return;
    }
    
    // if here, either a new user logged in or their city was changed
    
    // make sure loading is set to true
    if (!loading) {
      setLoading(true);
    }
    
    if (!userCity) {
      // user logged in, but city is unknown.
      setDeliveries([]); // no deliveries to show at this time
      return;
    }
    
    // List pending deliveries in user's city
    const unsubscriber = dbh
      .collection("deliveries")          
      .where("taken", "==", false)
      .where("city", "==", userCity)
      .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        const deliveries = [];

        querySnapshot.forEach((documentSnapshot) => {
          deliveries.push({
            ...documentSnapshot.data(),
            key: documentSnapshot.id,
          });
        });

        setDeliveries(deliveries);
        setLoading(false);
      });
    return unsubscriber;
  }, [user, userCity]); // rerun this effect only if user or userCity is updated

  return ( /* ... your render code ... */ )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your problem is that the second request depends on the first one. I would recommend to separate those two requests into two `useEffect` and make the second one depended on the value of `userCity`. That way the second request will run only when the `userCity` is changed and it would work in realtime. By adding a check if a `userCity` is set we can awoid requests we don't need.

The code would look like this:

```js
export default function Notifications({ navigation }) {
  const userUID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  const dbh = firebase.firestore();

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true); // Set loading to true on component mount
  const [deliveries, setDeliveries] = useState([]); // Initial empty array of users
  const [userCity, setUserCity] = useState(""); // Initial empty array of users


  useEffect(()=>{
    const userci = dbh.collection("users").                 // Fetching city field in user data
    .doc(userUID)
    .onSnapshot((doc) => {
      const usercit = (doc.data().city);
      setUserCity(usercit);
    })
  },[])

  useEffect(() => {

    if(userCity==''){
      return
    }

    const subscriber =  dbh
    .collection("deliveries")      // Recover deliveries around him according to his city    
    .where("taken", "==", false)
    .where("city", "==", userCity)
    .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
      const deliveries = [];

      querySnapshot.forEach((documentSnapshot) => {
        deliveries.push({
          ...documentSnapshot.data(),
          key: documentSnapshot.id,
        });
      });

      setDeliveries(deliveries);
      setLoading(false);
  });
    return () => subscriber();
    }, [userCity]);
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you very much, my mistake was to put everything in a single UseEffect if I understand correctly that makes one function dependent on the other? And a little more silly question about the last line " }, [userCity]);"  why did you put this here?